# Calculating the percentage for label and textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input a few input fields that the user can enter the values the first time they visit the particular page, these values get saved to the database and the function is called every time that you enter a value into the textbox as it will display the percentage of the 5 values from the total.

When the user leaves the form and comes back the labels are shown instead of the text boxes. Is the below code the right direction for such a task that would dynamically select the correct parameter ".text" or ".val" specifically to get the values since the labels get populated the next time the user comes back? I would like to automate this process instead of appending each label value by myself.

I have marked where I am having trouble

```
function calcABC(e) {

//Declare array of numeric selectors
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var x = "";
var y = "";
if (e == "label") {
    x = "lbl_"
    y = ".text()";
}
else {
    x = "txt_"
    y = ".val()";
}

//HAVING TROUBLE HERE VVVVVVV
alert(eval("$('#' + x + arr[0]) + y)"));
alert("hello");

//loop through the array and get the value for that array index
var before = 0;
for (var i in arr)
{
    before += isNaN(parseInt($("#"+ x + arr[i]).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($("#" + arr[i]).val())
}

//Apply the total to the global variable
ABCTotal = before;

//Loop through the numbers and get the precentage value and append the value to the relevant area
for (var j in arr)
{
    console.log($("#" + x + arr[i]).val())
    var val = isNaN(parseInt($("#" + x + arr[j]).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($("#" + arr[j]).val());
    $("#txt" + arr[j] + "Prec > small").text(calcPrec(val).toFixed(2) + "%");
}

//Set the total field
$("#txt_ABCTotal").text(ABCTotal);
}
// Nice function to quickly calculate the precent value from a total
function calcPrec(val)
{
    return (val * 100) / ABCTotal;
}
```

I hope that makes sense! Anyways any help appropriated!

Comment: You asked for something, then gave the solution you have so far. You should add what is not working with your current solution.

Comment: Updated the code where I am having trouble to parse the parameters for jquery to read. (specifically the alert ones)

Comment: To avoid use of eval, which is highly recommended I would do `y = 'text'` or `y = 'val'` and then `$('#' + x + arr[0])[y]()`
What is your specific problem though, what error do you get?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @MisterJ that worked, thank you.

Comment: @imBlue added as an answer for future user if you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid use of eval, which is highly recommended it is better to do y = 'text' or y = 'val' and then call the function with the array notation like :

```
$('#' + x + arr[0])[y]()
```